# rails conditional belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

My table `location`:

1. pos_long
2. pos_lat
3. belongs_to (ORG,PROJ,etc)
4. remote_id

I am trying to setup a relation in Location model:

```
belongs_to :organization, ->{Location.for_org},class_name: 'Organization',foreign_key: 'remote_id'

scope :for_org, ->{where({belongs_to: 'ORG'})}
```

The belongs_to field is at locations table but the query that gets made is wrong:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: 
Unknown column 'locations.belongs_to' in 'where clause': 
SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` WHERE 
`organizations`.`id` = 99 AND `locations`.`belongs_to` = 'ORG' LIMIT 1
```

The Location.organization should return a valid record only if Location.for_org is true and nill otherwise.

How can I fix this?

(I know polymorphic relations, but they change field names in funny ways that I dont want)

Comment: You say your locations table has a "belongs_to" column but the error says it doesn't, maybe you are mixing the concepts of a table and an activerecord model? I'm not sure your explanation of your design and what you want is clear enough, I don't really understand it (Location.for_org is a scope, it can't return true nor nil, it returns a collection)

Comment: The join that is made does not include the locations table, just org table. And thats why the query fails. I not good at Rails so my code has errors in design as well. But I only need a conditional relation, so when I have a loc_obj.organization will only return a valid object when two conditions are TRUE, `loc_obj.belongs_to=ORG` and the foreign_key is found in org table.

Comment: That stuff you wrote isn't valid code. You need to tell us the specific fields on your tables. I'm guessing "belongs_to" is not a field on your `locations` table.

Comment: belongs_to is a field in locations table. The fields shown are correct.

Comment: @thevikas: Can you double check the table name that is in your mySQL db? is it `location` or `locations`?

Comment: Are you trying to setup an association where a location can belong to different models on different tables? In that case you want a polymorphic association and you can create a scope based on the association_name_type column that you need to create.

Comment: Can you show your models? it's not clear wher you have those scopes. If you want to do a join and you have that Organization has_many Locations (or something like that) you can join both tables with Orgenization.joins(:locations), but I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to do.